# Button redirecting to php file

Tags: php, sql, forms, verify

when i press the 'continue' button i'm redirected to form's php functions file ( localhost/install/hamburgher.php ),but that must check if the code is correct or it will display an error.

hamburgher.php (functions on clicking of the button):

```
<?php 
session_start();

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($db,"licensecode");


// escape string
function e($val){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
}

$errors = array(); 

function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo $error .'<br>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['btn_lic']) && $_POST['btn_lic'] == 1)) 
{
    checkkey();
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "License key is invalid.");
}

// USER
function checkkey(){
    global $db, $username, $errors;

    // grap form values
    $key = e($_POST['key-get']);
    // make sure form is filled properly
    if (empty($key)) {
        array_push($errors, "A license key is required.");
    }

    // attempt login if no errors on form
    if (count($errors) == 0) 
    {
        $password = md5($password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM licenses WHERE code='$key' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) 
        { // found
            // check
            $keycode = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if($keycode['expired'] == 1)
            {
                array_push($errors, "This license has expired.");
            }
            else
            {
                header('location: step_4.php');
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            array_push($errors, "License key is invalid.");
        }
    }
    else {
            array_push($errors, "Some errors there.");
    }
}
```

Form file - step_3.php:

```
<?php

        include('hamburgher.php');
        require_once("settings.inc");    

        if (file_exists($config_file_path)) {        
        header("location: ".$application_start_file);
            exit;
      } 

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $application_name;?> Instalation Wizard - 3</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/brand/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/basic.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>


    <body>
    <center>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="../images/brand/logo_wide.png" alt="Thos Host Complete Solutions">
      <form method="post" action="hamburgher.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="step2" /> 
        <div class="container">
          <b><div style="font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;">Step 3: Insert your license key</div></b><br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="key-get" style="margin-right: 80%">Code:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="key-get" placeholder='38904ADSUFH8ADS7FH8ASHFASHF8ASHUFHA8SUFHU8ASHF8UHA' size="30">
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo display_error(); ?>
        <span class="step_active" >1</span>
        <span class="step_active">2</span>
        <span class="step_active">3</span>
        <span class="step_inactive">4</span>
        <span class="step_inactive">5</span>
        <button type="submit" class="button button_black" name="btn_lic" value="1" style="margin-left : 60%; color: white; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;"><b>Continue</b></button>
      </form><br>
    </div>
    </center>

    <?php include_once("footer.php"); ?>   

    </body>



    </html>
```

The code must display an error if:
- the input code is null;
- the input code is expired;
- the input code is not existing;

on displaying of error,the page must be same,but with `<?php echo display_error(); ?>` on the page,there will be the error message.

You must be redirected on page `step_4.php` if the code is found in database and is not expired

I know,i know,i will modify the code to avoid SQL injections,this is a beta code.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so what is the question? On form submit, display_error() doesn't show anything?

Comment: When i press the button (and the code is not input or is not correct) i'm redirected to hamburgher.php,is not creating an error in the same page with "You didn't input the code" (also when the code is correct all is working fine) [EDITED]

Comment: But your form goes to `<form method="post" action="hamburgher.php">`, once submitted it loads that page, you are not anymore on `step_3.php`. If you want to go back, you'd have to redirect back to step_3.php, `header("Location: step_3.php");`

Comment: Although, in that case, you lost the error output, let me think a bit about it

Comment: I added for debugging if button is pressed:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_lic']) && $_POST['btn_lic'] == 1)
{
 checkkey();
}
else
{
 header("Location: step_3.php");
 array_push($errors, "License key is invalid.");
}```

Even if i press the button i'm redirected to step_3.php ,that means hamburgher.php didn't detected if btn_lic is pressed,but i made all correct,why?

Comment: I think you should put the code from `hamburgher.php` into `step_3.php` and then remove the action for the form so it goes back to the same page. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to solve the issue would be to move the code from `hamburgher.php` to `step_3.php` and then remove the action for the form so it goes back to the same page.